# Makefile error: syntax error: unexpected word (expecting "fi")

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

I have a problem with the following section of a Makefile:

```
if [ -d "$(MODLOOP_FIRMWARE_EXTERNAL)" ]; then \
    if [ ! -e "$(MODLOOP_DIR)"/lib/firmware ]; then \
        mkdir -p "$(MODLOOP_DIR)"/lib/firmware; \
    fi \
    cp -r "$(MODLOOP_FIRMWARE_EXTERNAL)"/* "$(MODLOOP_DIR)"/lib/firmware/; \
fi
```

`make SHELL='sh -x'`:

```
if [ -d "/mnt/firmware" ]; then \
    if [ ! -e "/mnt/build-env"/lib/firmware ]; then \
        mkdir -p "/mnt/build-env"/lib/firmware; \
    fi \
    cp -r "/mnt/firmware"/* "/mnt/build-env"/lib/firmware/; \
fi
sh: syntax error: unexpected word (expecting "fi")
```

If I remove the line:

`cp -r "/mnt/firmware"/* "/mnt/build-env"/lib/firmware/; \`

it will work, but I can't see what the problem is.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `;` after this `fi` in the fourth line.

Comment: Probably the only thing I didn't try. Thank you.